# Looking for Answer to Basic Java Question

Tags: java

I wanted to know why the outcome comes like this whenever I input the correct answer. I'm sorry because this is my first time self-learning java.
Here is the result it displays:
"You have the correct answer too high"

```
class TestingJava
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
        throws java.io.IOException
        {
            char ch, 
            answer1 = 'L',
            answer2 = 'l';
            System.out.println("Guess a letter between A and Z.");
            System.out.print("Can you guess it: ");
            ch = (char) System.in.read(); // get a char
            if (answer1 == ch || answer2 == ch) 
            {
                System.out.println(" You have the correct answer " );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print( "Sorry your guess is ");
            
            }
           // a nested if
           if (answer1 < ch && answer2 < ch) 
           {
               System.out.println("too low"); 
            }
           else
           {
            System.out.println("too high");
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us the input values, the expected output, and the actual output? Also, what are the '#' values in your question?

Answer (score 2):

There is a logic problem with this line:

```
if (answer1 < ch && answer2 < ch)
```

When it comes to less than, the characters are ordered such that all the lowercase characters are first, and then later all the uppercase characters.

So if you enter a "z" for example, this would be considered less than "L".

I suggest you accept the input and then convert it to uppercase.  Then you only need `answer1`

Comment: Actually, lowercase character 'z' is bigger than 'L'. When you do the comparison ```'z' < 'L'``` it will evaluate to false.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will take an approach to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's your control flow, change the flow of your program to only check if the answer is too high or low if the guess is wrong (in the first else block):

```
        if (answer1 == ch || answer2 == ch) 
        {
            System.out.println(" You have the correct answer " );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print( "Sorry your guess is ");
            // a nested if
            if (answer1 < ch && answer2 < ch) 
            {
                 System.out.println("too low"); 
            }
            else
            {
                 System.out.println("too high");
            }
        
        }
```

This way you will only append the too high/low if the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will take an approach to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems with your code.

1. I assume you are going to end the program when the guess is correct. If this is the case then you should prevent the execution of the if-else block at the end. For example with a return statement:

   ```
   if (answer1 == ch || answer2 == ch) 
   {
       System.out.println(" You have the correct answer " );
       return;
   }
   ```
2. I assume you expect the expression below to evaluate to true if `ch` is alphabetically higher than the letter L.

   `(answer1 < ch && answer2 < ch)`

   It won't be the case since in ASCII, all lowercase characters are in fact bigger than all uppercase characters. For example, when you do the comparison below, it will evaluate to true.

   `'c' > 'Z'`

   So, in order for your expression to return true, `ch` must be a lowercase letter alphabetically higher than the letter L.

   Take a look at the table below to have a better idea how primitive char comparison works and design your program around it.

```
|---------|---------|----|--------------|--------------|--------------------------------|
| answer1 | answer2 | ch | answer1 < ch | answer2 < ch | (answer1 < ch && answer2 < ch) |
|---------|---------|----|--------------|--------------|--------------------------------|
|    L    |    l    |  a |      true    |      false   |             false              |
|---------|---------|----|--------------|--------------|--------------------------------|
|    L    |    l    |  l |      true    |      false   |             false              |
|---------|---------|----|--------------|--------------|--------------------------------|
|    L    |    l    |  z |      true    |      true    |             true               |
|---------|---------|----|--------------|--------------|--------------------------------|
|    L    |    l    |  A |      false   |      false   |             false              |
|---------|---------|----|--------------|--------------|--------------------------------|
|    L    |    l    |  L |      false   |      false   |             false              |
|---------|---------|----|--------------|--------------|--------------------------------|
|    L    |    l    |  Z |      true    |      false   |             false              |
|---------|---------|----|--------------|--------------|--------------------------------|
```

Note: Having said all this, as @ww has commented, converting the user input to lowercase or uppercase would make things easier for you.

Comment: Thank you for your brief information, I will take an approach to my code.